# Mask the data coming from Kafka stream

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming, spark-structured-streaming, spark-streaming-kafka

I am using spark Structured streaming to stream data from kafka, which gives me dataframe with below schema

```
Column     Type
key        binary
value      binary
topic      string
partition  int
offset     long
timestamp  long
timestampType   int
```

Value Colum is coming here in binary format buts its actually a json string with a struct type and the requirement is to read the json struct and mask few fields coming in it and write the data.